# How to use private repos in Dockerfile on circleci

Tags: docker, go, circleci

I'm getting started with build and deploying a small go app using circleci. My app also uses a private repository, and I've set up circleci with the ssh key to fetch that repo.
So in the build job, I have a go mod download step and that works fine.

The next step is building the docker image, in the Dockerfile I do a go build like this;

`go build -o app ./app/`

This also downloads the dependencies, one of which is a private repo. What would be the best path forward here? Should I be passing the ssh key into the dockerfile, so it can be fetched within docker?

Answer (score 1):

So after some more detailed digging around, it seems different jobs run in different containers or build environments, so the step after it has no access to the private repos that were already downloaded.

To get around this I'm passing the github key like so:
`extra_build_args: --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"`

and I'm using this orb circleci/gcp-gcr@0.13.0.

Then in my Dockerfile:
I do some formatting and set up using ssh instead of https.

Example is this:

```
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && umask 0077 && echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
&& git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/ \
&& ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ENV GOPRIVATE github.com/my-private-org/secret-repo
```

Open to any other suggestions as well. So far this is working for me.